# Maven skipping dependency files?

Tags: maven

I am using maven for my project. I have 5 local jar files as dependent files which i have specified in pom.xml as follows:

```
    <dependency>   
    <groupId>EWSAPI</groupId> 
    <artifactId>EWSAPI</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1</version> 
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/EWSAPI1.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>   
    <groupId>jcifs</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId> 
    <version>1.3.15</version> 
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/jcifs-1.3.15.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>   
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId> 
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId> 
    <version>1.4</version> 
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/commons-codec-1.4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>   
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId> 
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId> 
    <version>3.1</version> 
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>   
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId> 
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1.1</version> 
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Now, when i try mvn install in command prompt to install the dependencies. I get the following message

```
The following files where skipped:
   EWSAPI:EWSAPI:java-source:sources:1.1
   commons-codec:commons-codec:java-source:sources:1.4
   commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:java-source:sources:3.1
   commons-logging:commons-logging:java-source:sources:1.1.1
```

and also one file jfis was skipped(the same that was mentioned above as a dependency)

I do not understand why maven is doing so? I appreciate your help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-internal-site</id>
        <url>file:///${basedir}</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then remove the system path argument.

Also, are you sure the scope should be system?

Answer (score 1):

From the question, it is not clear what you are trying to do.

On one hand you mention `I have 5 local jar files as dependent files` and you have specified them with `<system>` scope in `pom.xml`.  On the other hand you mention running `mvn install` `to install the dependencies`.

You should avoid `<system>` scope unless there is a compelling reason, especially for third-party dependencies (like `commons-codec`).

`mvn install` builds the specified project and installs the same in the local repository. It does not *install* `dependencies`.

You can use `mvn install:install-file <params>` to `install` the dependencies *to the local repository* after downloading them separately.  They do not get `installed` in `${basedir}`.

Do update your question suitably if the above does not help.